# Inconsistency between browsers with style='width:100%;' if there is a CSS display definition

Tags: css, width, display

I am finding different behaviours between browsers. I have a TABLE which is dynamically generated so the width should be computed from the parent DIV:

```
<html>
<body>

<div style='width:800px; border:1px dotted blue;'>

<table style='width:100%; display:inline-block; font-size:40px;'>
<tr><td>1</td><td align=right>2</td></tr>
</table>

<table style='width:100%; display:inline; font-size:40px;'>
<tr><td>1</td><td align=right>2</td></tr>
</table>

<table style='width:100%; display:block; font-size:40px;'>
<tr><td>1</td><td align=right>2</td></tr>
</table>

<table style='width:100%; font-size:40px;'>
<tr><td>1</td><td align=right>2</td></tr>
</table>

</div>
</body></html>
```

Safari and Opera correctly shows the column '2' at the right border of the DIV. Chrome and Firefox appear to ignore the width:100% if there is a display definition. At the 4th case, there is no display definition and the table is correctly rendered.

Any idea why ?

Answer (score 0):

The width of all the tables are 800px. However, in Chrome and FF the width of the tbody element doesn't equal to 100% of its parent where the display property of the table element is not the default one.

There's no W3C definition for what the width of the tbody element is supposed to be in case that the display property of the table is not the default one. This encourages different implementations in different browsers.